# How to define the length of a global array in a function on Arduino?

Tags: c++, arrays, global, arduino

Is something like this possible in C++ (on Arduino)?

```
#include "stdio.h"

String str = "foo";

int i[strLength()]; // <- define length of array in function

int strLength() {
  return str.length();
}

int main(void) {
   ...
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using C++ or C? C does not have any "String" objects.

Comment: in fact I am using Arduino, which uses C++ I think.

Comment: What type is `String`? Is it `std::string`? Some specific type in your platform?

Comment: `String` is an Arduino string (http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject). Arduino doesn't have support for any part of the STL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You would need `i` to be a pointer and allocate the array in your `main`:

```
int *i = NULL;

// etc.

int main(void) {

    i = (int*) malloc(sizeof(*i)*strLength());

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: hm thank you!
would it be a good idea to use code like this (with malloc) on an embedded platform like arduino?

Comment: @Marcel The arduino compiler might support alloca(which uses stack instead of heap but same interface) , see if you can include <alloca.h>.

Comment: @Marcel It seems to work on my machine, so the syntax would be `i = alloca(sizeof(*i)*strLength());`. Just make sure that you do not return from whatever function that you allocate in until you do not need the array any more(i.e. do not create a seperate little function that just allocates the array).

Comment: @Marcel:  By declaring i as a pointer instead of just an array, all the code that reads or writes from i will be a little bit slower because the compiler does not know at compile time where the array is actually stored in memory.  Every time it needs to access the array it has to first read the value of the pointer into a special register for pointers, then it can start accessing actual values of the array.  This makes things slower but you probably won't notice, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: @DavidGrayson The other option of predefining the length of the array doesn't seem quite elegant. I only have two of those arrays with dynamic length in my program. I'll see if the speed is sufficient. Thank you!

Comment: @marcel Generally it is not recommended to use malloc in an embedded microprocessor applications where the Arduino is typically used. Since the arduino has limited resources, what will you do if the malloc fails?

Comment: In fact the length of the array is not really very dynamic. The array should have the length of a String that is also a predefined global variable. Therefore the malloc is only used once for each of the 2 arrays in the setup() function. It would however be even better to check if malloc was successfull or not. Is there a way to check that?

Comment: What type is `String`? If these strings are just hardcoded `char *` arrays, you could statically declare `i` based on the size of the string by using `sizeof`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using c++, the correct solution is a std::vector.
You will need to look at the docs for std::vector, but here is a conversion of your code to std::vector.

You then use std::vectors the same way you use regular arrays, with the "[]" operator.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

String str = "foo";

int strLength() {  // Needs to come before the use of the function
  return str.length();
}

std::vector<int> i(strLength() ); //Start at strLength


int main(void) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Are you saying everyone using C++ should always be using std::vector?  The OP is compiling his code for an 8-bit microcontroller that has 32 KB total of program memory and runs at 20 MHz, so avoiding templates and the standard library could save significant resources, but I'm not sure how much.

Comment: @David Either way he is going to have to dynamically allocate his array. While things such as iostreams will have a large run time cost, the cost of using a mostly compile time std::vector should be small.

Comment: @David But you are right, in that for certain cases alloca combined with the Jim's answer will be better than using std::vector which is designed for only heap.

Comment: Sorry, it actually runs a little slower: 16 MHz.

Comment: avr-gcc (the compiler used by Arduino) does not currently support any part of the STL so using `std::vector` isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not what you were hoping for, but I would just do something inelegant like this:

```
String str = "foo";
#define MAX_POSSIBLE_LENGTH_OF_STR 16

...

int i[MAX_POSSIBLE_LENGTH_OF_STR];
```

The idea is that you allocate more space for the array than you actually need, and just avoid using the extra parts of the array.

Alternatively, if you aren't going to be changing the definition of `str` in your source code very often, you could save some RAM by doing this:

```
String str = "foo";
#define LENGTH_OF_STR 3

...

int i[LENGTH_OF_STR];
```